# Bash Script Comparing File Sizes Issue

Tags: bash, if-statement, size

I'm running OS X.

So I'm having problems with a script to compare a file's size on my local HD, and a server.
To do so, I use cURL to get the http header, and trim it to the size in KB.
Then I use "stat" to get the local file's size.

Here's my code:

```
clear
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

Local=$(stat -f "%z" ./Google.png)
Remote=$(curl -sI http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png | grep Content-Length | awk '{print $2}')
declare -i Local
declare -i Remote
echo $Local
echo $Remote

if [ $Local != $Remote ]; then
  echo "Different sizes."
else
  echo "Same size."
fi
```

No matter if the sizes are equal or not, I get:

```
7007
7007
Different sizes.
```

I'm really desperate on this one, can anyone help?

Comment: Most likely the value you are getting from Remote has a non-printable character that is getting put into the variable, such a \r. Look at the echos using hexdump. Also, you can use if (( $foo != $bar )) for integer comparison. You current implementation is comparing strings.

Comment: I always echo with something like `echo ="${Local}"=` to help me be more sure what is in the variable. (It's not 100% perfect, but it catches a lot of silly mistakes in my logic)

Comment: @Aaron McDaid: if you're using bash, `printf "=%q=\n" "$Local" is even better at showing invisible chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl's output has lines terminated with carriage-return+linefeed (\r\n), not just linefeed (\n); the carriage return is getting included in the value of Remote, and causing the confusion.  You could remove it by piping through `tr -d "\r"`, but it's probably simpler to have awk do it (and the search, for that matter):

```
Remote=$(curl -sI http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png | awk '/Content-Length/ {sub("\r",""); print $2}')
```

BTW, I don't think that the `declare -i` commands are doing anything useful (since Local and Remote have already been set).

Answer (score 3):

Use `[ $n -eq $k ]` for comparing numbers.